# Two column equal height layout using table/table-cell with off-canvas sidebar

Tags: html, css, layout, sidebar

I'm trying to implement a two column equal height layout and have decided to use the CSS table and table-cell rules as it appears to be the easiest method with the least downsides. I would like the sidebar column to be a toggleable off-canvas column however I can't seem to make the main column take up the full width when the sidebar has moved off-canvas. I have tried various margin/position values to no avail. Here's my code and a JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/RaAbF/1/

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
  <header id="header">
    <a id="toggle-sidebar" href="#">toggle</a>
    [header]
  </header>
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="sidebar">
      [sidebar]<br>
      [sidebar]<br>
      [sidebar]<br>
      [sidebar]<br>
      [sidebar]<br>
      [sidebar]<br>
      [sidebar]<br>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      [main]<br>
      [main]<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  border-left: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
  border-right: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 70px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.outer:before,
.outer:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.outer:after {
  clear: both;
}

#header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #999;
}

#inner {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

#main {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

body.hidden-sidebar #inner {
  position: relative;
  left: -220px;
  right: 0px;
}

body.hidden-sidebar #main {
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle-sidebar').click(function(e) {
    $('body').toggleClass("hidden-sidebar");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: I would say a bit of Javascript is the easiest option, here's one I wrote http://optdesign.co.uk/equal-heights-responsive/ it's optionally responsive also. There's lots of others